# UITableView doesn't animate deletion if multiple cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have my `UITableView` (swipe) deletion method set up in the standard fashion.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        /*
        code…
        */

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        }   
}
```

The `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` animation works perfectly if there is only one cell in the table view or if I am deleting the last cell, but if I try to delete a row above the last one, it will no longer use the animation when I hit delete. How can I fix this?

Also, I am using a custom cell (just a label and an image view) if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but for anyone having this issue, I have created a test project that replicates the required functionality, with animation working perfectly for all cells.

It's available here: https://github.com/sdods3782/TVTTableViewTest

However, I was unable to recreate the issue. I don't know what was causing the problem for the original poster, but using TVTTableViewTest as an example, it should hopefully prevent other people from having the same problem.